# Scripting for bash screen

Tags: bash, unix, gnu-screen, backgrounding

I have processes that I background with screen.  I'm trying to write a script that attaches to a terminal, executes a couple commands, then detaches.  The problem is that when I attach to a terminal, screen directs control to the user.  How do I work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Screen has an option -X which you can use to remote-control a screen session from within a script.  See, for example, [here](http://www.jerri.de/blog/archives/2006/05/02/scripting_screen_for_fun_and_profit/).

Comment: That lets me send screen commands to screen.  Is there any way to send arbitrary commands to the terminal running inside screen?